# How to use Azure Service Bus between Website and REST Web API

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azureservicebus

I've done a ton a research and cannot figure out how to use service bus in a real world scenario.

I have a web site that communicates with a REST API and I'd like to have a service bus in between the two.

Having tasks in the service bus queue will allow my web site to remain fast while things are sent to the REST API in the background.  I think this is a common scenario.

PS.  My REST API uses basic authentication.

So right now I'm looking for sample code to handle this specific scenario, but cannot find anything.

I have two ideas, but not sure what the service bus can handle...

1. Is the service bus queue capable of holding the entire REST message and passing it to the REST API and handling authentication?
2. ...OR does the service bus queue just hold an ID that I use to pull data from SQL and process the task?  In other words... I need a "listener" app which polls the queue and takes the bits of data to create the message and send it the REST API.

Is there someone that wouldn't mind clarifying how this scenario would work... what's the best way to do this?

Comment: I think the normal way of This is to have the website talk with your rest api. Which put the job on a servicebus. A worker role is then responsible of executing the jobs and the website can then ask the rest api of the current status or rely on signalr to push status updates.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I don't need the REST API to put something in Service Bus.  I can do that directly from the Web Site.  However, I do need to issue a POST to the REST Endpoint to start a task.  In other words, I want to expose a REST Endpoint to Service Bus.  But maybe Service Bus can't talk to a REST Endpoint.  Is Service Bus more of dumb queue that just holds a string of data?  I think if I used your suggestion I am creating a polling and processing app and not even using my existing REST API.  Do I understand correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Use webjobs and Queuetrigger.

1. Website to Service bus queue.
2. Webjobs to read message received in the queue using queuetrigger. You can host webjobs in rest api
3. Do processing in the webjobs.